# How to remove Index in multiple array if specific String is detected

Tags: arrays, swift

Ive been searching for at-least an hour with no luck. There are a lot of question similar to this one but that do not give the correct answer.

What I'm trying to do is simply I have an array for a notifications table:

Code:

```
var notificationList = [(Type: "Work", Date: "7/7/7", Seen: false), (Type: "Home", Date: "8/8/8", Seen: false),(Type: "Fun", Date: "9/9/9", Seen: false)]
```

It has the value specifying the type of notification it will be, the date it was created and if it has been seen or not.

I can append a new notification to the list by using this.

Code:

```
 notificationList.append((Type: "Work", Date: "8/8/8", Seen: false))
```

The problem that I'm trying to find out how to solve is. If I can search for the slot called *Date* and then say remove all index's that have the string 8/8/8 in the date slot.

Seems simple enough haha.

So far I can do this but this code will make me match every single slot in the array in order for it to work.

Code:

```
notificationList = notificationList.filter(){$0 != (Type: "Work", Date: "8/8/8", Seen: false)}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To filter for all notifications whose `Date` is not `"8/8/8"` write

```
notificationList = notificationList.filter{ $0.Date != "8/8/8" }
```

It's highly recommended to use

- A struct rather than a tuple
- Lowercased parameter labels / variables since `Date` can be confused with the struct `Date` in Swift 3

Comment: Wow that it lol thanks. its work all I had to do is add ($0.date).